# Websocket disconnects Openshift

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, openshift

Compiled files of chat websocket example that comes with Tomcat 7 works fine on localhost and Openshift.

However, when I compile those files myself it doesn't work on Openshift, although on localhost still works great (tomcat 7).

I tried to compile through netbeans, eclipse, and terminal (OSX). Tried all versions of dependencies, tried building as java webapp, maven webapp, tried to upload as war file but no success.

The module I'm trying to test is the chat websocket. It is composed by two classes, one xhtml file and two dependencies.

working: http://chatoriginal-helioha.rhcloud.com:8000/examples/websocket/chat.xhtml

not working: http://chat-helioha.rhcloud.com:8000/websocket/chat.xhtml

I'm not changing a single line of code, so the files I compile myself should be the same as the ones that comes already compiled right?
I also tried to decompile files using www.javadecompilers.com to see if there was anything extra there but I couldn't find any difference.

There are only three files on this project and they are shown bellow.

ChatAnnotation.java

```
package websockets.chat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.apache.juli.logging.Log;
import org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory;

import util.HTMLFilter;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/chat")
public class ChatAnnotation {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ChatAnnotation.class);

    private static final String GUEST_PREFIX = "Guest";
    private static final AtomicInteger connectionIds = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static final Set<ChatAnnotation> connections =
            new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

    private final String nickname;
    private Session session;

    public ChatAnnotation() {
        nickname = GUEST_PREFIX + connectionIds.getAndIncrement();
    }


    @OnOpen
    public void start(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
        connections.add(this);
        String message = String.format("* %s %s", nickname, "has joined.");
        broadcast(message);
    }


    @OnClose
    public void end() {
        connections.remove(this);
        String message = String.format("* %s %s",
                nickname, "has disconnected.");
        broadcast(message);
    }


    @OnMessage
    public void incoming(String message) {
        // Never trust the client
        String filteredMessage = String.format("%s: %s",
                nickname, HTMLFilter.filter(message.toString()));
        broadcast(filteredMessage);
    }




    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
        log.error("Chat Error: " + t.toString(), t);
    }


    private static void broadcast(String msg) {
        for (ChatAnnotation client : connections) {
            try {
                synchronized (client) {
                    client.session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.debug("Chat Error: Failed to send message to client", e);
                connections.remove(client);
                try {
                    client.session.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // Ignore
                }
                String message = String.format("* %s %s",
                        client.nickname, "has been disconnected.");
                broadcast(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTMLFilter.java

```
package util;

/**
 * HTML filter utility.
 *
 * @author Craig R. McClanahan
 * @author Tim Tye
 */
public final class HTMLFilter {


    /**
     * Filter the specified message string for characters that are sensitive
     * in HTML.  This avoids potential attacks caused by including JavaScript
     * codes in the request URL that is often reported in error messages.
     *
     * @param message The message string to be filtered
     */
    public static String filter(String message) {

        if (message == null)
            return (null);

        char content[] = new char[message.length()];
        message.getChars(0, message.length(), content, 0);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(content.length + 50);
        for (int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            switch (content[i]) {
            case '<':
                result.append("&lt;");
                break;
            case '>':
                result.append("&gt;");
                break;
            case '&':
                result.append("&amp;");
                break;
            case '"':
                result.append("&quot;");
                break;
            default:
                result.append(content[i]);
            }
        }
        return (result.toString());

    }


}
```

chat.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Apache Tomcat WebSocket Examples: Chat</title>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
        input#chat {
            width: 410px
        }

        #console-container {
            width: 400px;
        }

        #console {
            border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
            border-right-color: #999999;
            border-bottom-color: #999999;
            height: 170px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #console p {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    ]]></style>
    <script type="application/javascript"><![CDATA[
        "use strict";

        var Chat = {};

        Chat.socket = null;

        Chat.connect = (function(host) {
            if ('WebSocket' in window) {
                Chat.socket = new WebSocket(host);
            } else if ('MozWebSocket' in window) {
                Chat.socket = new MozWebSocket(host);
            } else {
                Console.log('Error: WebSocket is not supported by this browser.');
                return;
            }

            Chat.socket.onopen = function () {
                Console.log('Info: WebSocket connection opened.');
                document.getElementById('chat').onkeydown = function(event) {
                    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                        Chat.sendMessage();
                    }
                };
            };

            Chat.socket.onclose = function () {
                document.getElementById('chat').onkeydown = null;
                Console.log('Info: WebSocket closed.');
            };

            Chat.socket.onmessage = function (message) {
                Console.log(message.data);
            };
        });

        Chat.initialize = function() {
            if (window.location.protocol == 'http:') {
                Chat.connect('ws://' + window.location.host + '/examples/websocket/chat');
            } else {
                Chat.connect('wss://' + window.location.host + '/examples/websocket/chat');
            }
        };

        Chat.sendMessage = (function() {
            var message = document.getElementById('chat').value;
            if (message != '') {
                Chat.socket.send(message);
                document.getElementById('chat').value = '';
            }
        });

        var Console = {};

        Console.log = (function(message) {
            var console = document.getElementById('console');
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
            p.innerHTML = message;
            console.appendChild(p);
            while (console.childNodes.length > 25) {
                console.removeChild(console.firstChild);
            }
            console.scrollTop = console.scrollHeight;
        });

        Chat.initialize();


        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Remove elements with "noscript" class - <noscript> is not allowed in XHTML
            var noscripts = document.getElementsByClassName("noscript");
            for (var i = 0; i < noscripts.length; i++) {
                noscripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(noscripts[i]);
            }
        }, false);

    ]]></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="noscript"><h2 style="color: #ff0000">Seems your browser doesn't support Javascript! Websockets rely on Javascript being enabled. Please enable
    Javascript and reload this page!</h2></div>
<div>
    <p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="type and press enter to chat" id="chat" />
    </p>
    <div id="console-container">
        <div id="console"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that when working with websockets on OpenShift, the confusing part could be the port binding: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html. If that does not answer your question, you may want to add some more details about the error ('rhc tail <yourAppName>').

Comment: Great point! But I believe I'm using port 8000 already to access websocket, but still no success. I have updated the post with complete code and links to both working and not working versions of the chat example on openshit.